# SVG output of MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I have a basic `MathJax` code of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/SVG"],
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<div>$$a = b + c$$</div>
```

I expect the formula should be replaced with an `SVG` code, but the result is the same as HTML output, MathML codes:

```
<div>
    <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
    <span class="mjx-chtml MJXc-display" style="text-align: center;">
        <span id="MathJax-Element-1-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" tabindex="0" data-mathml="
            <math
                xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;>
                <mi>a</mi>
                <mo>=</mo>
                <mi>b</mi>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mi>c</mi>
            </math>" role="presentation" style="font-size: 113%; text-align: center; position: relative;">
            <span id="MJXc-Node-1" class="mjx-math" aria-hidden="true">
                <span id="MJXc-Node-2" class="mjx-mrow">
                    <span id="MJXc-Node-3" class="mjx-mi">
                        <span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.224em; padding-bottom: 0.279em;">a</span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="MJXc-Node-4" class="mjx-mo MJXc-space3">
                        <span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-main-R" style="padding-top: 0.058em; padding-bottom: 0.335em;">=</span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="MJXc-Node-5" class="mjx-mi MJXc-space3">
                        <span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.445em; padding-bottom: 0.279em;">b</span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="MJXc-Node-6" class="mjx-mo MJXc-space2">
                        <span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-main-R" style="padding-top: 0.279em; padding-bottom: 0.445em;">+</span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="MJXc-Node-7" class="mjx-mi MJXc-space2">
                        <span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.224em; padding-bottom: 0.279em;">c</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation">
                <math
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
                    <mi>a</mi>
                    <mo>=</mo>
                    <mi>b</mi>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <mi>c</mi>
                </math>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-1">a = b + c</script>
</div>
```

How can I get the output as SVG vector elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MathJax configuration script should be type of `text/x-mathjax-config` not `text/javascript`. Moreover `?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML` seems to be somehow overriding the `output/SVG`. I used `?config=default`. You can get more information about the configuration files [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html)

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/SVG"],
    })
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
<div>$$a = b + c$$</div>
```

Comment: How do you get this code to work in a basic html file?

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by putting in html / body tags, but there's not rendered SVG when I view source in Chrome.

Comment: Ahah, found it there is when you go to right-click page "inspect".  It shows the rendered tags there.  Thank you!

Comment: Viewsource shows the original html without running any JavaScript. SVG is drawn via JavaScript. Inspect allows you to see what's on the screen currently. Glad you solved on your own 

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still using MathJax 2.7.x, modifying the config parameter will work for rendering svg on initial load.

So change `TeX-AMS_CHTML` to `TeX-AMS_SVG`

or change `TeX-MML-AM_CHTML` to `TeX-MML-AM_SVG`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG"></script>
```